# How to prevent ScrollView scrolling down when a child has textIsSelectable="true" attribute?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Previously, this was the layout for my **DialogFragment**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".InfoDialog"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <!-- (More Views here) -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

It works fine. However, I need to make **textView1** *selectable*. But when I add the `android:textIsSelectable="true"` attribute to it, **scrollView** is scrolled down a bit when the dialog is displayed. (NB - I am able to scroll it up to the top manually, but that's obviously not a solution.)

I've tried adding `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` to **scrollView**, but that hasn't worked.

I've also tried this in my `onCreateDialog()` and `onViewCreated()` methods:

```
ScrollView scrollView = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

But that hasn't worked either - ie, **scrollView** is still scrolled down a bit when the Dialog is shown.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

Using this to the end of my `onCreateDialog()` works:

```
ScrollView scrollView = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
scrollView.post(() -> {
    scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
});
```

However, it's not an ideal solution (esp. as you can see the scroll being performed on-screen). Is there a better solution, preferably xml?

Comment: try using nestedscrollview it will work.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.

Comment: do you know how the above 'textIsSelectable' attribute works? here is it for you https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextIsSelectable(boolean)

Comment: Which one? And why do you ask?